# How to re-use artifacts from different pipeline in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 pipelines in 2 different repositories:

- lib.yml in repo.git produces a re-usable library artifact A (needs multiple stages on different nodes for that) and also has a stage that runs autotests after A has been produced.
- app.yml in app.git builds and tests an application that needs A to build.

In app.yml I want to integrate A without duplicating lib.yml. I was told that templates are a solution, but I am not so sure. Multiple stages of lib.yml must run before I can consume the desired artifact. Using job templates would only complicate both pipelines and create a dependency on pipeline internals. app.yml should not know how lib.yml builds A.

After consulting the docs I think that a pipeline resource is closer to what I need. But I do not fully understand how it works. Let us assume we want artifact A from lib.yml on branch B.

1. Will app.yml use the latest available artifact A of branch B or will it kick lib.yml on B?
2. Is there a way to tell app.yml: use the latest A of lib.yml for branch B if available, otherwise run lib.yml on B and wait for A to become ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, you are right - [resource pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines) should do a job for you.

And to run app.yml you should have sth like this:

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: hadar
    source: kmadof.hadar
    trigger:
      branches:
        - B
```

and use just:

```yaml
- download: hadar
```

to get latest artifact from pipeline of branch B.

You can also select pipeline running your app.yaml manual and select artifact:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And `- download: hadar` also gets correct artifact.

So

1. app.yml will use latest available artifact A of branch B.
2. If you want to app.yaml trigger lib.yaml and then get artifact from lib.yaml it would be difficult and not possible using out of the box functionality. So there is no out fo the box way to have app.yaml trigger un lib.yaml and waiting for artifacts from lib.yaml. And if your app yaml will be triggered by an other trigger than resoure pipeline trigger it will use latest available artifact A of branch B.